# Is there a way of disable creating a .pem file when launching an instance in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

My question is about this: Let´s say a user wants to launch an instance in AWS. Is there a way to tell AWS to not let them launch it with a .pem file? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you just using user data to configure the machine?

Comment: Exactly. And in the end of the process, i don´t want the .pem choice pop up...

Comment: Do you want to prohibit the action of creating new key pairs (pem files)? If so, only during the instance launching process (key pairs can be created independently also)?

Comment: I do indeed want to prohibit the action of creating new key pairs (pem files). As a starter, making it possible during launching process helps me. For making the same thing for the keys created independently, i think i should open another thread with the question. I you happen to know how to do it both ways, it is great for me!! :)

Comment: Probably there is no such way with IAM policies. You have to make a custom solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

When using the AWS CLI, the `--key-name` parameter is optional.  From [this link](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html#examples)

> The following `run-instances` example launches a single instance of type `t2.micro` into the default subnet for the current Region and associates it with the default subnet for the default VPC for the Region. **The key pair is optional if you do not plan to connect to your instance using SSH (Linux) or RDP (Windows)**.

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
    --image-id ami-0abcdef1234567890 \
    --instance-type t2.micro \
    --key-name MyKeyPair
```

(Bold text mine)  So you do not need to supply a key pair when creating from the CLI.  However, it looks like the UI to spin up an EC2 requires the key pair though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The thing is that i want to deny users in the account that choice. I mean, i don´t want it to be optional. And i want to make it possible also in the UI, not only the CLI :)

Comment: Ok, then how about delete the `authorized_keys` file as part of your user data setup.  For example, with an Ubuntu instance the file `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` holds the public key that can be used to log in.  It's ugly but no matter what the user did they can't log in with ssh.

Comment: The thing is that i use that path to access with my CA, so i need it to exist...

Answer (score 0):

While You Creating any AWS EC2 instance from the GUI console or AWS CLI, *attaching KeyPair is always optional to it*.
an AWS EC2 instance can be created without using the .pem file and also if you configure the **session manager**, you can log in to it using AWS Console GUI.

> aws ec2 run-instances 
> --image-id < ami-id> 
> --instance-type < instance-type> 
> --subnet-id < subnet-id> 
> --security-group-ids < security-group-id> < security-group-id>

you can remove this parameter in the CLI command and that will do the needful without.pem file.

--key-name < ec2-key-pair-name>

Comment: Hi @Vinayak Singh, i know attaching KeyPair is optional...The thing is that i don´t want it to be optional. I want it to be forbidden...